# Installation of MSP430's IDE Energia in Ubuntu

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to install Energia for Ubuntu but until now the only thing that I have successfully managed to do is download the binary release version for Ubuntu! I have searched everywhere to find instructions and there some forums that try to provide them but they don't! I have started to lose my faith. Does any of you working with MSP430 microcontroller can explain simply how to install Energia in Ubuntu 14.04? Please don't provide links to other sites/forums because I am 100% sure that I have checked them all. Literally I have searched up to the 7th page in Google and every single page is purple as a result of visiting them all...

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it but I actually found a solution. Because, as I said in the question, I have searched extensively and most of the solutions were very messy and unclear I answer my question in the hope that it will help others and save them the hours I spent on this problem myself. This solution was hidden in a thread of a forum:

So in order to install Energia:

1. Download the binary release version from the energia site
2. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
3. Install the "Main Menu" package
4. From the first column select Accessories
5. Click New Item, name it Energia and select the file energia from the unzipped downloaded Energia binary release
6. Select Ok
7. Write Energia in Launcher and click on the Energia entry.

After that one must set up the serial communication with the Launchpad board. From another source I manage to find a solution to solve that problem doing the following:

1. `sudo lsusb`
2. `sudo modinfo cdc-acm`
3. Then create a file called `71-persistent-msp430.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory
4. Add this line in it:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="0451", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f432", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"`

5. `sudo adduser user plugdev`

Write your own username instead of user.

6. `sudo service udev restart`

Also it may need to change the Board from Energia's toolbar (Tools and after Board).

Comment: Looks like steps 2-7 of your first instruction is simply to let the launcher find the unpacked file. You could probably skip all of that and just open a terminal and run the program from there; or open the directory it contains and double click it; or make a shortcut on desktop.

Comment: @Shahbaz I am new to Ubuntu and this solution is a complete one composed out of others scattered in the internet.